# Phongap build useing splash.9.png as default splashscreen for android

Tags: splash-screen, phonegap-build, nine-patch

[Phone gap build documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) states that:

> The default splash must be named splash.png and must reside in the
>   root of your application folder.

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

but they also say:

> Patch-9 backgrounds are supported. All patch-9 files have to have a
>   ".9.png" suffix.

Does this mean that I can use

```
<gap:splash src="splash.9.png" />
```

as the default ?

Comment: I know that this comment may not help, but have you tried it? When you disable splashcreen auto hide via config.xml, it should be easy to verify?

Comment: Trying does not seem to help...
It does not look as if its interpreted as a 9 patch at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, according to the documentation, you can't use a 9-patch image as default splash.
Extracts from the [Phonegap Build Documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) page:

> The default splash must be named splash.png and must reside in the root of your application folder.

and

> All patch-9 files have to have a ".9.png" suffix.

I suggest the following solution: Use the same splash.9.png source for all Android sizes and you will have a similar result. One file for all screens.

```
<gap:splash src="splash.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="splash.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="splash.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="splash.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="splash.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="splash.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxxhdpi" />
```

Still, the default splash.png must be present, but will not be used on Android.

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

Comment: 1) I would love to see where it says that "you can't use a 9-patch image as default splash".. I could not find such a statement.

Comment: 2) IMHO and if memory serves me well - this would not work as you do not adhere to "The default splash must be named splash.png and must reside in the root of your application folder."

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will take some time to verify this and the accept if this is indeed the case.

Comment: we decided to provide defferent files for the different resolutions b ut it looks like basicly this is the way to go.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had to make sure that I had specified all of the `gap:qualifier="*"` as shown in this answer. Specifying a single `<gap:splash src="splash.9.png" gap:platform="android" />` is incompatible and does not display 9-patch images correctly.